# Ract Native: first time user onboarding with AWS Amplify

Tags: reactjs, react-native, authentication, aws-amplify

not really sure if this is possible, but I'd like to implement an on-boarding flow for first time users of a react native app after they sign in. I'm using AWS Amplify, and I'm not sure if there is a way to check if it's the users first time signing in - or maybe I should have a postConfirmation trigger add them to a group which forces them through a few pages, and the event of completing these pages drops them from that group and refreshes?

My alternative option is to explore putting a react-navigation stack navigator in the amplify `<Authenticator>` component, something like this:

```
import { Authenticator, SignIn } from 'aws-amplify-react-native';

// The override prop tells the Authenticator that the SignUp component is not hidden but overridden
<Authenticator hideDefault={true}>
  <SignIn />
  <MyCustomSignUp override={'SignUp'}/> 
</Authenticator>
```

Where `<MyCustomSignUp>` would be a stack navigator as opposed to a component or screen...

Has anyone seen an on-boarding flow implemented with Amplify and React Native?
Would my implementation work?
Are there any examples?

Thanks for any help, I've been looking for *anything* for days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible, i've implemented it in my Amplify app, you need to implement `react-native-onboarding-swiper`, customize it, and then import it in your App.js, along with useEffect and a conditional statement.
Follow this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SMkR-iIGvwQ